# Recursive search with Beautiful Soup

Tags: recursion, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract info from nested html tags:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="cover_1" class="default"></div>
    <div id="container_2">
        <div class="blue">
        <div id="container_3" class="red">
</div>
```

However, when I try to inspect the children of container_2 by:

```py
container_2tag = soup.find("div", id = "container_2")

children = container_2tag.findChildren()
```

the children list is empty and so I cannot dig deeper into the structure. I've looked at the answers explaining the iteration over tree tags using findAll but couldn't find a problem where html nesting is not visible to Beautiful Soup. Could it be a bad parser? (I've got html5lib installed)..

Comment: Could you please provide the full code you've written (with imports and valid html)?

Comment: Sure:`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

new_url = "http://www.skyscanner.net/flights/lond/nyca/130515/130525/airfares-from-london-to-new-york-in-may-2013.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(str(new_url)))
day_combined = soup.find("div", id = "day_combined")

children = day_combined.findChildren()
print children`

Comment: When I look at html doc it is indeed not nested. It's only in Firebug that the nested information is visible..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a tag with the id container_2tag

do

```
container_2tag = soup.find("div", id = "container_2")
```

And the children can be found

```
>>> children = container_2tag.findChildren()
>>> children
[<div class="blue">
<div id="container_3" class="red">
</div>
</div>, <div id="container_3" class="red">
</div>]
>>> children[0]
<div class="blue">
<div id="container_3" class="red">
</div>
</div>
>>> children[1]
<div id="container_3" class="red">
</div>
>>> children[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: if I do ``container_2tag = soup.find("div", id = "container_2")`` then it works, see edited answer

Comment: ok, my problem is then that the dummy html I provided was the Firebug version of the file - this nesting does not seem to be visible in the raw html as in the browser - why would that be?

Comment: perhaps some javascript is calling a server side process and then modifying the dom?  If this is the case you might have to use something like scrapy that can do client side javascript during the retrieve

Comment: so that's html:`<div id = "results_container">
      <div id="active_cover" class="hidden"></div>
      <div id="day_combined" class="hidden"></div>
      <div id="day_singles" class="hidden"></div>
      <div id="day_airlines" class="hidden"></div>
            <div id="day_singles_summary" class="hidden"><div class>`    and that's Firebug html: `<div id="results_container">
<div id="active_cover" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="day_combined">
<div class="viewport">
<div class="day_resultslist sorted-px">
</div>`how can I tell what is going on?

Comment: where `class = "viewport"` and `class="day_resultslist sorted-pk"` are embedded in `<div id="day_combined">`

Comment: yep the data is being populated via javascript call